# Появляется ошибка, не могу понять, как ее исправить

Tags: 1с

```
{ВнешняяОбработка.ЗагрузкаПриобретенияИзЭксель.Форма.Форма.Форма(133,20)}: Тип не определен (Запрос)
                Запрос = Новый <<?>>Запрос; (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, указывайте больше информации в вопросе, чтобы другие могли понять в чем конкретно проблема, а не просто код ошибки увидели.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы пытаетесь описать запрос на клиенте. Перенесите запрос в процедуру с директивой на сервере:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ВыполнитьЗапрос()
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    //..... 
КонецПроцедуры
```

Описание доступности из синтаксис-помощника:
**Доступность**:
Сервер, толстый клиент, внешнее соединение, мобильное приложение(сервер).